# Big theta notation for nested loop with division

Tags: javascript, big-o

I'm trying to solve this function for big theta notation.

I'm assuming the outer loop is log(n) and the inner loop is (n)? so as a whole, it would be nlogn?

```
var total = 4;
    var c = 6;
    for(var v = c ; v > 0 ; v = Math.floor(i/4 ))
        for(var x = 0; x < Math.pow(c,2); j++ )
            total++ ;

    console.log(total);
```

Comment: Weird question given this very inefficient code.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop is going from 0 to n^2, so it's really n^2 * log n. Also, the base of the logarithm is 4.

Comment: The inner loop is actually "going from" 0 to n²-1. Also, in Landau notation and for estimations of the order of magnitude of a time complexity in general, multiplicative constants do not matter, and the base of the logarithm is therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Math.pow(n, 2)` is `n` squared and `j` is incremented by 1 at each inner loop iteration, the inner loop has time complexity Theta(n²) (in fact its body is executed exactly n² times per loop). The outer loop's body is executed Theta(log(n)) times as you correctly guessed.

The resulting complexity is Theta(n²log(n)).